# An approximation algorithm for partitioning metric completed graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, approximation

Given complete metric weighted graph $G=(V,E)$ with $n$ vertices. Are there an algorithm that partition $G$ into to disjoint part $(C_1,C_2)$ that sum of heaviest edge $e\in C_1$ and heaviest  edge $e'\in C_2$ minimized?

I seek for a paper that include an algorithm for above problem that run it's algorithm in $O(n^2)$, because i have an paper that find optimal solution in $O(n^3)$.

Comment: I edit my question. I seek for an algorithm with $O(n^2)$ running time.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Do you want an approximation (like the title says), or an exact? Which paper gives the n³?